# How does Google S2 / Hilbert Curve handle the outliers?

Tags: google-maps, google, geohash

Regarding [Google S2 library](https://github.com/google/s2geometry), it used for a quick indexing on locations.
E.g. near by locations would have similar indices. Thus it's much easier to make location queries.

But, as we map a 2-D point to 1-D point, it's bound to lose some precision.
E.g. the following case, points are close but indices are far away.

Is there a pattern for the outliers and how does google s2 cope with it?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question and relevant to other types of spatial search structures, such as geohashes.

Comment: Correcting S2 lib link, official repository is at https://github.com/google/s2geometry  (the old `code.google.com/archive/p/s2-geometry-library` was abandoned)

Comment: About tags: S2 is not used in *Google-maps* (they use [OLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Location_Code) as [geocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocode)).

Answer (score 1):

[Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and S2geometry **libraries offers a kind of "neighbors algorithm"**, that is a **fast calculation of the cell ID of the 8  neighbors** of a cell. From them you can check if there are outliers.

See for example   https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html

[image]

Similar thing in **S2 Geometry** library is **S2ClosestPointQuery**: see description at [Guide](http://s2geometry.io/devguide/cpp/quickstart#s2closestpointquery) or at [source code](https://github.com/google/s2geometry/blob/master/src/s2/s2closest_point_query.h).

---

All illustrated Geohash cells of same `gbs`  prefix are neighbors. Some (6 of 8 = 75%) has same `gbsu` prefix, others, calculated, has the `gbsv` prefix. The *"check same prefix" algorithm* **is easy** for humans and computers, but it is not guaranteed for a [full recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

---

### NOTES

Geohash uses no projection, and Geohash cells of the same hierarchical level have different areas (latitude-dependent distortion). S2 Geometry is not perfect but corrected the problem by a [fast projection transform](https://s2geometry.io/devguide/s2cell_hierarchy.html#coordinate-systems), resulting in a [near-equal-area grid](https://s2geometry.io/resources/s2cell_statistics.html), in each level.

Apart from these basic differences, both can be used as local square-grid, and its cell identifiers can be used as [geocodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocode#Hierarchical_grids). S2 geometry is based on  the Hilbert curve (see [its geocodes here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/294823/7505)), and Geohash based on the Morton curve: **for both** the *"near by locations would have similar geocodes"* hypothesis is valid only for ~60% of cases where compared geocodes has same prefix. See  an [intercative demonstration](https://ppkrauss.github.io/Sfc4q/).

[image]